# What is causing this nativescript installation error on Macbook Pro

Tags: nativescript

I have installed, uninstalled, cleaned npm cache and reinstalled.  Still getting the following error and being new to MacBook Pro, I have no idea what is going on.

> Johns-MBP:~ jbaird$ npm install -g nativescript npm WARN optional
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: abbrev@1.1.0
>   (node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev):
>   npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, rename
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev'
>   -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.abbrev.DELETE'
>
> npm ERR! path
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi-regex
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! syscall rename npm
>   ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi-regex'
>   -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.ansi-regex.DELETE'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/jbaird/.npm/_logs/2017-08-24T14_34_26_019Z-debug.log
>   Johns-MBP:~ jbaird$

Comment: what is your npm version?

Comment: The node version is 6.11.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same issue. What worked for me was to

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript
```

then `npm install nativescript -g`

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same error.

I did simply removed nativescript module using `sudo npm remove -g nativescript`.

And now installed nativescript module using `sudo npm install -g nativescript`.

Comment: @JRichardsz Dockerfile is for docker containers and this solution is for development on macOS.

Comment: Hi @Laxmikant , this warning was detected in my linux environment: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/....DELETE'. When I converted my app to docker, the warning still appear with or without your tip.